# Does a modal overlay require absolute positioning?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's a JS fiddle of what I am talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/r77K8/98/

My overlay gives the appearance of having disabled the link, but the link still remains clickable. I looked through some examples of modal dialog windows in hopes of finding a solution. As far as I can tell I need to use absolute positioning.

I am hesitant to do so because in reality my content is dynamically populated. It seems like a lot of added work to try and keep the overlay the correct dimensions -- I really like how it looks right now, I just would like to make the controls unclickable while the overlay is the parent. Is this possible?

Comment: Your sample seems to work fine for me. After I click on the 'show overlay' link and the popup comes up, I can't click on 'show overlay' anymore until I close the popup.

Comment: JS fiddle gave me the wrong link -- its from an example I was looking at, crap. One moment. EDIT: It is fixed now. It's a really simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, it looks like you have the contents that you are trying to disable INSIDE the overlay div. In order for this to work, you need to put the overlay div OVER the contents, so place it after your contents. That way it covers up your content div.

And yes, your overlay should have absolute positioning so that you place it at the top-right corner of the parent container and give it 100% width and height, so that it covers the entire parent container.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r77K8/103/) for an example.

---

**EDIT**:

Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/r77K8/116/) instead. Put both the contents and the overlay in a container. That way, the overlay will only take up that part of the page.

Notice that the container divs (`divLink1` and `divLink2`) must have `position:relative` for this to work. According to the `absolute` description in [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp), "The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element." So you have to set the containers to `position:relative`, but don't actually move them.

Comment: Yes, I understand the concept completely. It is just frustrating because of the complexity/location of the content is I am trying to hide. The content can expand/contract after ajax calls, and I'm worried that my overlay will look like it is trying to 'catch up' when it tries to recover content after it expands.

Comment: Do note that your jsfiddle does not make the link appear to be disabled -- you've lost that functionality. Instead, it does disable clicking the link, but doesn't fade it out, but it appears to just be an opacity setting.